# How can I say that some action has an "investment nature"?

Tags: phrase-choice

I can't find a correct phrase with the word "nature" in English. Literally, an operation has an investment nature or is of an investment nature. I've searched it on Internet, but Google hasn't shown a lot of results. When something has any nature or features or peculiarities, how you express it?

Is it possible to use "investment nature"?

Comment: I know people that are of a friendly nature, but I really wonder if people of an "investment" nature are interesting to be around. Your use of _investment_ as attributive seems original, to say the least. I'v heard of an investment plan, investment capital maybe, but investment nature? What exactly do you mean with that?

Comment: I mean that the operation has special characteristics related to investment. This operation can be classified as that related to investment. I am not speaking about people now. I need to use "nature" with the "operation".

Comment: Well, in the correct context _an operation of an investment nature_ would be understood just fine, I think. But I doubt it is a commonly used expression.

Comment: Do you mean investment in the sense that the operation is involved with financial investments like stocks, bonds, etc.? And do you mean operation as a "procedure of productive activity" or as a "business, especially one run on a large scale".

Comment: No matter what, don't use *an investment nature/is of an investment nature* in any case! :) Find something else. Maybe, *this operation requires an investment* or the like.

Comment: @ Maulik V thanks for the opinion.  This operation has elements that belong to the sphere of investment. That is, if you analyze this operation, you can come to the conclusion that its elements are somewhat of investment activities.

Comment: @ ColleenV This is a business aimed at generation of income. I don't mean securities and transactions with them. A business uses facilities or means to create something that will bring future benefits.

Comment: @MaulikV actually "of an investment nature" is fairly common to distinguish between transactions that are simply the cost of doing business and transactions that are made with the expectation that there will be an increase in value in the future.

Comment: @ColleenV you mean investment as an adjective?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Definition 2 when running a google search for 'define nature' suggests:  the basic or inherent features, character, or qualities of something.  So, yes 'investment nature' relating to an operation is fine.

To illustrate, if a company chooses to spend its annual profit on a lavish party for the executives that operation could be criticised for not being of an investment nature.  The criticism could suggest operations that are of an investment nature, such as supplying staff with training, putting money into R & D, upgrading equipment in the office etc that would be a better use of the company's profit.

Comment: That's it. I am choosing "of an investment nature". Thanks.